# Displaying amount - Python

Tags: python, printing, currency

```
print("The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: $", round(paint_costs,2))
The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: $ XXX.XX
```

How do I omit the space between the $ and amount so that it reads:

```
The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: $XXX.XX
```

Is it `import.locale`?

Comment: in your case, using string formating is the correct answer: `"The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: ${0:.2f}".format(paint_costs)`. Don't use `round` to format numbers.

Comment: If you think the solution has answered your problem, then please mark it as accepted. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  `sep=""` parameter inside the print function.

```
print("The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: $", round(paint_costs,2), sep="")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Py3 feature `sep`

```
print("The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: $", round(paint_costs,2),sep = "")
```

Other ways include

- `print("The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: ${}".format(round(paint_costs,2)))`
- `print("The cost of paint based on whole gallons is: $%s"%(round(paint_costs,2)))`